# On discrete log calculation - safe primes need

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cryptography

Given a prime $r$ consider $g^z=h\bmod r$ where $z$ is unique mod $r-1$ where $r-1=2pq$ for primes $p,q$. Does this help simplify the discrete logarithm problem?

Comment: A Chinese remainder theorem approach allows then the following reduction: find the discrete log of $h^p$ (a modulo $2q$ problem) and the discrete logarithm of $h^q$ (a modulo $2p$ problem). If $p$ and $q$ are both much smaller than $r$, say $O( r^{1/2})$, then this leads to significant savings.

Comment: Just to be clear you are saying $$g^{zp}=h^p\bmod r$$ $$g^{zq}=h^q\bmod r$$ will be solved first and then we solve for $z\bmod p-1$?

Or is it  solving $$g^{zp}=h^p\bmod 2q$$ $$g^{zq}=h^q\bmod 2p$$  first and then getting $z\bmod (p-1)$?

Comment: The former (the latter doesn't make any sense). This is assuming that we are using a black box cyclic group approach to DLP (such as Pollard-$\rho$, or baby step - giant step). Instead of solving the problem in a group $\Bbb{Z}_r^*$ of order $r-1$, we solve two problems in groups of respective orders $p$ and $q$ (and $2$), namely in the subgroups $(\Bbb{Z}_r^*)^p$ and $(\Bbb{Z}_r^*)^q$. Because the complexity $M(n)$ of a black box cyclic group of order $n$ is exponential (in $\log_2n$) $M(2)+M(p)+M(q)\ll M(2pq)$.

Comment: Lost me there I'm afraid :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am just wondering if sieve tricks can benefit from this?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen what is blackbox cyclic group?